# Batch job user wakes Windows from Sleep and Hibernate unintentionally

Tags: windows-10, sleep-mode, hibernation, local-security-policy

I've 1 Admin and 1 Local user on Windows 10 machine and Sleep and Hibernate behaved as expected: PC awoken from Sleep by key/mouse press and from Hibernate only on power button press.

Yesterday I've added a new user to the PC with a "Log on as a batch job" Local Security Policy and with a Task Scheduler task that runs an app as that user -- all exactly as described in this instruction: https://www.mysysadmintips.com/windows/home-and-media/555-setup-minecraft-server-to-start-automatically
or as screen-captured here (for those with false-positive malware warnings):
[image]

---

My problem is that the Sleep and Hibernate don't function anymore as expected -- the change (it seems) makes them automatically interrupted and PC awakens immediately.

My first guess was that the Task had some Power options wrong, but this (to me) looks OK:
[image]

What can I change (apart from removing the task/new user) to have Sleep and Hibernate function as before?

Comment: Added a screenshot of the linked page with setup instructions...

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with network adapter allowing the media player waking up the PC (as it was using it as source for its library).

Disable these:

[image]
[image]